# Why does dt$ not delete until the end of line?

Tags: object-motions

I understand that the right way to delete until the end of line is d$, but why does dt$ not work also?

Comment: `D` would also work, I think.

Comment: Start here: `:h operator`, and keep reading until you reach the end of the file, these are things you'll be using all the time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because `t` takes a character, so it looking for a literal `$` character, not a motion like end of line

Answer (score 5):

`t` (and its variants `T`, `f` and `F`) take a single character afterwards to denote the target of motion within the line.

So the effects of the two commands are:

- `d$` - delete to end of current line
- `dt$` - delete up-to-but-not-including a literal $ on the current line